# I don't understand notation in python documentation

Tags: python

I don't understand notation in python documentation.

The notation is like,

```
functools.reduce(function, iterable[, initializer])
functools.partial(func[,*args][, **keywords])
```

What is mean [, initializer] or [,*args]? 
I can understand we can use three arguments in python reduce function, but the thing is [, ~] notation.

Comment: The square brackets (perhaps unfortunate since [] is a `list` normally) come from EBNF meaning optional.

Comment: I'm new to EBNF! Thanks!